# WCF Web Service, Java Web Client, MustUnderstand headers not understood?

Tags: wcf, jax-ws, apache-axis, soapfault

I'm hosting a WCF Web Service with the following WSDL (a simple service using wsHttpBinding and SSL for transport security):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="MagicEightBallService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_TransportSecurity_IMagicEightBallService_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:TransportToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.local.domain.name/MagicEightBall/MagicEightBallService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://my.local.domain.name/MagicEightBall/MagicEightBallService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IMagicEightBallService_GetAdvice_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAdvice"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IMagicEightBallService_GetAdvice_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAdviceResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IMagicEightBallService">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAdvice">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IMagicEightBallService/GetAdvice" message="tns:IMagicEightBallService_GetAdvice_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IMagicEightBallService/GetAdviceResponse" message="tns:IMagicEightBallService_GetAdvice_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_TransportSecurity_IMagicEightBallService" type="tns:IMagicEightBallService">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_TransportSecurity_IMagicEightBallService_policy"/>
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAdvice">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IMagicEightBallService/GetAdvice" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="MagicEightBallService">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_TransportSecurity_IMagicEightBallService" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_TransportSecurity_IMagicEightBallService">
      <soap12:address location="https://localhost/MagicEightBall/MagicEightBallService.svc"/>
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>
          https://localhost/MagicEightBall/MagicEightBallService.svc
        </wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Why do I get errors when I try to consume this from Java?  When I try to consume it using Axis2/Java, I get the error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing : Action
```

And when I try to use JAX-WS, I get the error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action] are not understood
```

So far I haven't had any success with either of these, and I'm not sure whether a fix needs to be applied to the server or the client.

(See [a related question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666842/intellij-web-client-errors) for more details, including the WCF Web.config).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running:

```
ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
sc.engageModule("addressing");
```

engages the Addressing module, fixing this issue.

Comment: above solution is for Axis2 , any work around for JAX WS using metro ?

Answer (score 4):

I know the post is old, but someone may still face this problem.

I'm using JAX-WS, and I was having the same issue. After reading https://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-21-ea3/docs/wsaddressing.html#On_the_client_side I've found a solution that worked for me.

The code was breaking in the following line:

```
IFooService service = new FooService().getWSHttpBindingIFooService();
```

What I've done is the following:

```
IFooService service = new FooService().getWSHttpBindingIFooService(new javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature());
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

also add addressing.mar and soapmonitor.mar to your library path.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem.

In my case the webservice's WSDL was created using WCF in .net and we are consuming it at JAVA side. After several tries I noticed that the corresponding header was missing in the web service. I asked my dotnet team to add a - port name in the webservice.This port name just a normal name in the web service. This was needed because at JAVA side we need port type and port name to actually access the webservice.

Try to add below lines at the .net side inside the service and then try to consume at JAVA side.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "BookStockWebService", Name = "BookStock")]
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "BookStockWebServiceport", Name = "BookStockPort")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If client has been generated using Apache CXF and facing this issue, then below helps:

1. Add below annotation to IService interface:
   `@Addressing(enabled=true, required=false)`
2. In client class that is where the service is being obtained for calling:

`ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl(wsdl,service); IService port = service.getWSHttpBindingIService(new AddressingFeature(true));`

Import for AddressingFeature is javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature;